# Working with data from a form

Tags: forms

I am trying to create a module with a simple form. The form allows the user to enter their address, from there I need to take the user's address, make a geocoding request, then send the data to another api, and then I need to display the data from the api request.
The part I am having issues with is taking the submitted address so I can do the requests with it. How do I take the data from the form so I can use it? I do not need or want to save the data into my database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form submit handler, look in the form state. The `values` array will contain submitted values.

So for a form element, 'foo', generated like this:

```
$form['foo'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Foo'),
];
```

You get the value like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $value_of_foo_field = $form_state['values']['foo'];
}
```